# How to compare two Blitz++ Arrays?

Tags: c++, blitz++

I am trying to compare two Blitz++ Arrays, but I am getting a compiler error saying that the expression cannot be converted into a boolean.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz/files/3031673/blitz-0.9.pdf) this operation should be supported.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
#include <blitz/array.h>

int main() {
  blitz::Array<double, 2> a(1, 1);
  blitz::Array<double, 2> b(1, 1);
  bool c = (a == b);
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘blitz::BzBinaryExprResult<blitz::Equal, blitz::Array<double, 2>, blitz::Array<double, 2> >::T_result’ {aka ‘blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr<blitz::_bz_ArrayExprBinaryOp<blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr<blitz::FastArrayIterator<double, 2> >, blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr<blitz::FastArrayIterator<double, 2> >, blitz::Equal<double, double> > >’} to ‘bool’ in initialization
```

Comment: I don't know the library (which is why I'm posting this as a comment not an answer), but I see this in the docs: `All operators are applied *elementwise*.`. I think you're getting an array of two `bool` and need to reduce it by checking whether *any* or *all* (depending on your needs) are true.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo This could be, thank you! I've tried to change the line to `blitz::Array<bool, 2> c = (a == b);` expecting to get an array holding the booleans for the comparison of the individual elements, but I am still getting a similar error: `error: conversion from ‘blitz::BzBinaryExprResult<...> to non-scalar type ‘blitz::Array<bool, 2>’` requested.

Comment: always include entire error, not just 1 line of it.  Yes the rest looks confusing.  It is useful.

Comment: What's the purpose of using blitz here?

Comment: I am implementing a library for numeric algebra with compile time unit and coordinate system checks. So far it supports Eigen as a backend, I am adding support for Blitz++ atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
blitz::Array<bool, 2> result(a == b);
```

or

```
bool c = blitz::all(blitz::Array<bool, 2>(a == b));
```

the conversion from expression to array is explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, what I was looking for was `bool c = blitz::all(blitz::Array<bool, 2>(a == b));`

Comment: What's the purpose of using blitz here?

Comment: @Maf I'd ask the OP?  I'm just telling the OP how to get their code to compile.  The kind of error messages this mistake generates are hard to decode by C++ novices, but I recognized it, and found the part of the docs that says the conversion if explicit.  So I solved the error message.